# Trying to load an existing Makefile-based C ++ application into Eclipse fails to load

Tags: c++, c, linux, eclipse-cdt

I have build a C++ application that consists of two source code files and the Makefile:

```
myexample.h
myexample.c
Makefile
```

It compiles perfectly in linux Debian, executing in the terminal:

```
make
```

The application is compiled with gnu g ++ (originally it was a C application, but now I compile
it as a C ++ application, without errors).

These files are in the directory

```
/home/myuser/example1/src/
```

However, now I want this application to be compiled and edited from Eclipse.

The version of Eclipse that I use is:

```
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
```

I try to load the application that I already have in Eclipse following this procedure:

1. I start Eclipse and the "Eclipse IDE Launcher" window appears.
   In the "Workspace" box I write /home/myuser/example1
   I click the "Launch" button.
2. The "Welcome" screen is displayed in Eclipse, I close it.
3. I select the menu option
   File --> New  -> Makefile Project with Existing Code
4. In the "New Project" window, which is now displayed, I fill in the following fields:

   - "Project Name": example1
   - "Existing Code Location": /home/myuser/example1/src
   - "Toolchain for indexer Setings": Linux GCC
     I click the "Finish" button.

After doing this, no files are shown in "Project Explorer".

If I click "Build" it does nothing.

That is, it seems that Eclipse has not recognized or loaded my example correctly,
which however does compile manually with make and the executable works.

Any help or comment is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's `/home/myuser/example1/src/` and not `/home/myuser/example1/`?

Comment: Works for me (Win10, MinGW) without any problem. -- In the "Project Explorer", is the MyLyn option (violet bubbles) active? If so, deactivate it. -- You might like to open the C/C++ perspective viw the "Window" menu.

Comment: It is a linux program.

Comment: SOLVED: I have moved the Makefile to a subdirectory that is one level above the source code and now Eclipse loads the code, compiles it and executes it.